# How should I decide whether to build a "protected interface"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, access-specifier

From: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/basics-of-inheritance.html#faq-19.9

> Three keys: ROI, ROI and ROI.
>
> Every interface you build has a cost and a benefit. Every reusable
>   component you build has a cost and a benefit. Every test case, every
>   cleanly structured thing-a-ma-bob, every investment of any sort. You
>   should never invest any time or any money in any thing if there is not
>   a positive return on that investment. If it costs your company more
>   than it saves, don't do it!
>
> Not everyone agrees with me on this; they have a right to be wrong.
>   For example, people who live sufficiently far from the real world act
>   like every investment is good. After all, they reason, if you wait
>   long enough, it might someday save somebody some time. Maybe. We hope.
>
> That whole line of reasoning is unprofessional and irresponsible. You
>   don't have infinite time, so invest it wisely. Sure, if you live in an
>   ivory tower, you don't have to worry about those pesky things called
>   "schedules" or "customers." But in the real world, you work within a
>   schedule, and you must therefore invest your time only where you'll
>   get good pay-back.
>
> Back to the original question: when should you invest time in building
>   a protected interface? Answer: when you get a good return on that
>   investment. If it's going to cost you an hour, make sure it saves
>   somebody more than an hour, and make sure the savings isn't "someday
>   over the rainbow." If you can save an hour within the current project,
>   it's a no-brainer: go for it. If it's going to save some other project
>   an hour someday maybe we hope, then don't do it. And if it's in
>   between, your answer will depend on exactly how your company trades
>   off the future against the present.
>
> The point is simple: do not do something that could damage your
>   schedule. (Or if you do, make sure you never work with me; I'll have
>   your head on a platter.) Investing is good if there's a pay-back for
>   that investment. Don't be naive and childish; grow up and realize that
>   some investments are bad because they, in balance, cost more than they
>   return.

Well, I didn't understand how to correlate this to C++ protected interface.

Please give any real C++ examples to show what this FAQ is talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, do not ever treat any programming reference as definitive. Ever. Everything is somebody's opinion, and in the end you should do what works best for you.

So, that said, what this text is basically trying to say is "don't use techniques that cost you more time than they save". One example of the "protected interface" they're describing is the following:

```
class C {
    public:
        int x;
};
```

Now, in Java, all the Java EE programming books will tell you to always implement that class like this:

```
class C {
    public:
        int getX() { return x; }
        void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    private:
        int x;
};
```

... that's an implementation of proper *encapsulation* (technical term: simplifying a little, it means minimizing sharing between discrete parts). The classes using your code are concerned that you have some way to *get* and *set* an integer, not that it's actually stored as an `int` inside the class. So if you use accessor methods, you're better able to change the underlying implementation later: maybe you want it to read that variable from the network?

However, that was a large amount of extra code (in terms of characters) and some extra complexity to implement that. Doing things *properly* actually has a cost! It's not a cost in terms of correctness of the code - directly - but you spent some number of minutes doing it "better" that you could have spent doing something else, and there is a nonzero amount of work involved in maintaining everything you write, no matter how trivial.

So, what is being said in this passage is in my mind good advice: always double-check that when you go to do something, you're going to get more out of it than what you put in. Sanity check that you are not following an ideal to the detriment of your actual effectiveness as a programmer or a human being.

That's advice that will serve you well in any programming language, and in any walk of life.

Comment: Wow, If that FAQ is saying that we should not bother too much about these classes, and do something else, than I think (personal opinion) the man is crazy! When you are working for a company, you have a good chance of getting thrown out for writing that knid of code. Yeah, well if you are writing only for yourself then it is a different issue. Thanks for your explanation btw.

Comment: @AnishaKaul What I'm saying is that you can get fired (or, more likely, go nowhere) by writing good code too slowly as easily as you can for writing bad code quickly. Saying "you should always do X" is rarely correct. The answer to most questions is between the extremes.

Comment: Okay, Well, I get it. [joke] Perhaps we should first write a bad code quickly , and show the boss that the task has been done, and then sit down quitely to make the code good! :) :) :) anyway, thanks for your effort. This faq entry wasn't worth the time!

Comment: This is actually a good example of where additional cost can pop up. If I try to read the value of `x` from a `const C`, the first example works but the second does not. It should have been `getX() const`! So by "doing it right", the code has a higher support cost!

Answer (score 0):

From your quote above, the guy sounds like a pedantic jerk :)

Looking at the *previous* entries in his FAQ, he's really saying the following:

1) A class has two distinct interfaces for two distinct sets of clients:

- It has a public interface that serves unrelated classes
- It has a protected interface that serves derived classes

2) Should you always go to the trouble of creating two different interfaces for each class?

3) Answer: "no, not necessarily"

- Sometimes it's worth the extra effort to create protected getter and setter methods, and make all data "private"
- Other times - he says - it's "good enough" to make the data itself "protected".  Without doing all the extra work of writing a bunch of extra code, and incurring the consequent size and performance penalties.

  Sounds reasonable to me.  Do what you *need* to do - but don't go overboard and do a bunch of *unnecessary* stuff in the name of "theory".

That's all he's saying - use good judgement, and don't go overboard.

You can't argue with that :)

PS:

FAQ's 19.5 through 19.9 in your link deal with "derived classes".  None of this discussion is relevant outside of the question "how should I structure base classes for inheritance?"  In other words, it's *not* a discussion about "classes" in general - only about "how should a super class best make things visible to it's subclasses?".

Comment: `Should you always go to the trouble of creating two different interfaces for each class?` On what basis should it be decided what to do in which case? Any C++ examples?

Comment: ` it's "good enough" to make the data itself "protected". Without doing all the extra work of writing a bunch of extra code, and incurring the consequent size and performance penalties.` Isn't the only way to make data protected is to label it 'protected'? What extra work are you talking off? those get and set functions which are needed  to fetch the data from protected members? Anyway this FAQ entry seems to be unimportant.